# Error when returned results have no logo

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an app with React making use of the Eventbrite API.

The app is called Eventfinder which allows you to search for events based on keyword(s), location and a given time.

The problem I have is that when an event doesn't have a logo specified I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'url' of null
(anonymous function)
src/components/util/EventBrite.js:18
  15 | if (jsonResponse.events) {
  16 |   return jsonResponse.events.map(event => ({
  17 |     id: event.id,
> 18 |     logo: event.logo.url,
  19 |     date: event.start.local,
  20 |     name: event.name.text,
  21 |     url: event.url
View compiled
(anonymous function)
src/components/util/EventBrite.js:16
  13 |     return response.json();
  14 |   }).then(jsonResponse => {
  15 | if (jsonResponse.events) {
> 16 |   return jsonResponse.events.map(event => ({
  17 |     id: event.id,
  18 |     logo: event.logo.url,
  19 |     date: event.start.local,
```

Here is the Eventbrite documentation with regards adding events https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/

I have tried to add a 'no image' placeholder and write something that says, if no image, show this placeholder. But unfortunately I can't get it to work.

Here is my Eventbrite.js file:

```
const myToken = 'token hidden';

const EventBrite = {

  search(term, location, date, sortBy) {
    return fetch(`https://cors- 
anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search?token=token hidden&q=${term}&location.address=${location}&start_date.keyword=${date}&sort_by=${sortBy}`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${myToken}`,
            Origin: `http://localhost:3000`,
          }
        }).then(response => {
          return response.json();
        }).then(jsonResponse => {
      if (jsonResponse.events) {
        return jsonResponse.events.map(event => ({
          id: event.id,
          logo: event.logo.url,
          date: event.start.local,
          name: event.name.text,
          url: event.url
        }));
      }
    });

  }

}

export default EventBrite;
```

Would I need to write a function above the return statement?

Any help greatly appreciated

Craig

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `event.logo` is null (since there's no logo) so you can't access `event.logo.url`.
One possible solution would be to check if this value is `null`, and if it is, set another logo url or nothing at all.

For this, I'm using a ternary operator like that :

```
if (jsonResponse.events) {
    return jsonResponse.events.map(event => ({
        id: event.id,
        logo: event.logo.url === null ? '' : event.logo.url,
        date: event.start.local,
        name: event.name.text,
        url: event.url
    })
);
```

Comment: Sounds logical. How would I go about adding an alternative logo? Would I add the file path of the backup image in place of the second event.logo.url?

Comment: If you want to show nothing if there's not logo, the above code will perform it. If you want an alternative logo (like to tell that there's no official logo), you can do this : `logo: event.logo.url === null ? 'url_to_alt_logo' : event.logo.url` where you replace `url_to_alt_logo` with either the url of the logo you want to show, or the path if it's stored on server.

Comment: I still get the same error if I try either a placeholder image or to show nothing. Also, will this just show no image for the one event that has no logo or for all of the search results? I think the first time i tried it all the images showed no image.

Comment: Only for those with no logo

Comment: I am still getting the, "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'url' of null" when trying both codes you suggested. Any ideas?

Comment: The following code works.

`logo: event.logo ? event.logo.url : 'no-image-available.png',`

However the file path to the image seems incorrect. The image is in the same folder as the file itself so I thought this should work.